# how to implement a Queue in java? faster is better

Tags: java, performance

This is a problem from an interviewer, to implement a queue in java. Basically， this queue  only needs to provide Enqueue/Dequeue operations.

Implementation with faster execution shall get a higher score. Assume each method will be called in same frequency. So, every method should be similarly fast.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like he was angling for the a ring buffer like the [disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/) library.

It can be as much as 10x faster than ArrayBlockingQueue.

I have written a library which is not quite as fast but solves a different problem which is queue persistence. It can be faster than ArrayBlockingQueue as well, but persists all the data and can be shared between processes. [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle)

---

" Assume each method will be called in same frequency. "  If this were true, you would only need a ring buffer of 1. The simplest being AtomicReference. Note: this is lockless and gc-less.

```
public class AtomicReferenceQueue<T> {
    private final AtomicReference<T> ringBufferOfOne = new AtomicReference<T>();

    /**
     * @return true if added.
     */
    public boolean add(T t) {
        return ringBufferOfOne.compareAndSet(null, t);
    }

    public void offer(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        while (!ringBufferOfOne.compareAndSet(null, t))
            if (Thread.interrupted())
                throw new InterruptedException();
    }

    public T poll() {
        return ringBufferOfOne.getAndSet(null);
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        T t;
        while ((t = ringBufferOfOne.getAndSet(null)) == null)
            if (Thread.interrupted())
                throw new InterruptedException();
        return t;
    }
}
```

In truth, ensuring exactly the same frequency is impossible on the micro-second level. This "ring buffer" would work best if the enqueue frequency were almost always lower than the dequeue frequency (and you don't mind burning a cpu ;)

Comment: Side note: I don't think the question generally asks for anything like a blocking queue or much related to concurrency... I think you were spot on with your suggestion of a ring buffer, though.

Comment: "Assume each method will be called in same frequency." sounds like a ring buffer ;)